# Step through third party code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm not able to step through third party code (xercesImpl.jar) after attaching the actual source in Eclipse's debug window.
The third party class methods are followed by `line:not available`.

Please suggest what to do.

I am able to see the source of third party after the attachment but breakpoint is not hit while debugging.

Comment: How did you attach the source? Have you tried navigating to the jar under "Referenced Libraries", right-clicking on it to the context menu item "Properties", selecting the "Java Source Attachment" pane, and then specifying the location of the source?

Answer (score 1):

Your library probably was compiled without debugging information.
Then you must replace it with a version that includes those. As you already have the source, it is likely the best you compile it yourself because then you are sure those line numbers match.

Debugging information can be included (or excluded) using the `-g` switch on the `javac` compiler. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Thank you. After compiling the code with xjavac with debug on or say -g for javac able to step through the code.

Comment: @user1445322  If that worked, you should 'accept' the answer, as a way of saying Thanks!